# REGEX_extract need to take part of the path

Tags: sql, replace, google-bigquery

I have a column named "path" and I want to create a new column with project names:

```
Folder/1//File/2//Project/AAA//Dataset/BBBB
Folder/1//File/2//Project/ZZZ//Dataset/XX55
Folder/1//File/3//Project/blabla
Folder/1//File/3//Project/hhhhhhh//Bucket/central
```

What I want to get is only the text after `Project/`, here is an expected output:

```
AAA
ZZZ
blabla
hhhhhhh
```

I've tried the `REGEXP_EXTRACT(REPLACE(path, '//', ''), r'Project/([^/]+)') as Project` command, but I am getting results like:

```
AAADataset
ZZZDataset
blabla
hhhhhhhBucket
```

Comment: Why do you remove `//`? Did you mean to replace with one `/`? Then use `REPLACE(path, '//', '/')`. Else, you lose the right-hand `/` in Project name "field". But you do not even need it, I think. Does `REGEXP_EXTRACT(path, r'Project/([^/]+)') as Project` work?

Comment: As simple as that, thank you Wiktor !

Comment: You may upvote & accept the answer if that answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a logical error: if you plan to match up to a `/` char, you should not remove it from the expected locations.

The `REPLACE(path, '//', '')` part removes all double forward slashes. If you remove it from the code above, you will be able to match up to the `/` or end of string with `[^/]*`.

Thus, the solution looks like

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(path, r'Project/([^/]+)') as Project
```